# AngularJS: Class scope is lost when method is called from another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component structured like so:

counter.tpl.html:

```
<h1>Count is {{$ctrl.count}}</h1>
<count-increment increment-func="$ctrl.increment"></count-increment>
```

counter.component.js:

```
class CounterController {   
    var count;
    constructor(){
        this.count = 0;
    }
    increment(){
        this.count++;
    }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).component('counterComponent', {
    templateUrl: "./counter.tpl",
    controller: CounterController,
})
```

Where `count-increment` is an external package's component.

The problem I'm finding is that when `count-increment` calls my `increment` function, the scope inside the function is that of the `count-increment` component, not my `counter-component`. So I am no longer able to access `this.count` (it is now `undefined`).

I found a way to make it work by having my controller's `$onInit` listen for a `countIncremented` event, which is broadcast inside the `increment` method by the `count-increment` root scope. But it is not obvious which component is accessing the root scope, or why the increment logic is inside the listener instead of the actual `increment` method.

Is there a better or more standard way to go about this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass your counter to that `count-increment` component like so:

```
<h1>Count is {{$ctrl.count}}</h1>
<count-increment increment-func="$ctrl.increment" counter="$ctrl.count"></count-increment>
```

And use two way data-binding in your `count-increment` component constructor:

```
...
controller: YourComponentControllerConstructor,
bindings: {
    incrementFunc: '&', 
    counter: '='
}
...
```

So when you try to access this.counter in your count-increment component's controller you will point it to your parent variable:

```
...
this.increment = function() { 
    this.counter++; // which refers to his variable declared on bindings that points to what you have passed on html component
};
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the `count-increment` component is an external dependency, so I can't modify the bindings.